# Laravel fresh install login issues

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5

RESOLVED
appearantly I was truncating my passwords as I set the column size for password too low

Yesterday I started using the PHP framework Laravel and I am very happy with it, except for one small part, this part being the standard login provided by the framework.

I created a new project in Netbeans and placed it in my xampp htdocs folder so I could access the site from a browser immediately.

I used the commands

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
cd laravel
composer install
```

This all seems to work fine, I created a database using the migrations that came with the clean install of laravel and registered a user which worked without a hitch.

However when I now try to log in it gives me the error message

```
Whoops! There were some problems with your input.
       -These credentials do not match our records.
```

I thought it might have been something I changed in the routes so it wasn't using the correct routes to the login post so I created a project from scratch and changed nothing except my database settings in the .env file but it still gives me the same message.

If anyone could give me some hints as to where in the code the problem could be I would be very grateful

Comment: Did you do `php artisan migrate` ? Did you create an account on your website?

Comment: I did not do a migrate, I created the database manually using phpmyadmin but I used the table definition in the migration files as a reference to create my tables.

I registered an account to the website and it is deffinitely in my database as I've checked both using sql and the phpmyadmin dashboard

Comment: How did you created the password ? Did you directly entered the password inside the db ?

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't do `php artisan migrate`? Anyway, being as you didn't, my suggestion would be to check that you definitely set the tables up correctly (including the correct lengths on the fields - it may be that your password field is being truncated).

Comment: No i used the already supplied register user feature for laravel that came with the fresh install, it is properly hashed in the database

Comment: Thank you very much alexrussel, I was indeed truncating my password, I thought I got the length safe by using a varchar 50 but appearantly it wasn't enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that because you manually created your database, you managed to miss a detail or two. My immediate thought is that your password field is not long enough and is being truncated (everything will *look* fine but it won't work).

Laravel's hashing functions need at least 60 characters for the password (and 100 for the remember token) as per the [authentication introduction](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#introduction).